# How to make flutter widgets adaptive to different screen sizes

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I`m using width and height params of Container to determine widget size. but the widget is not adaptive if tested on other devices. I came from native android where i used to use density independent pixels(dp) that is adaptive to any screen size. what is the equivalent to dp in flutter ?
I dont want to use MediaQuery every time to calculate screen width and height.

Comment: Some sample code would help, maybe there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: well, any sample code will work. just use a container and set width and height and test it on different screen sizes

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **SizeBox.expand** widget to let your widget expand to take the available space regardless of size [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)

```
SizedBox.expand(

  child:MyButton(),
),
```

And if you want to keep an aspect ratio regardless of screen size you can use the **AspectRatio** widget [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html)

```
AspectRatio(

 aspectRatio: 3/2,

  child:MyButton(),
),
```

If your widgets are just in a row or column and you want to add weights among them to fill the spaces you can use the **Expanded** widget

```
  Expanded(
            flex: 1,//weight for the widget
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              height: 100,
            ),
          )
```

,

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of your UI widgets this way:

```
 width: 100.0 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicPixelRatio ,
```

the function `MediaQuery.of(context).devicPixelRatio` will return the actual number of pixel in each logical pixel, so you'll be sure that the same 100.0 pixel on your test device are typical to those of the user whatever screen density they have.

Comment: if i want to set the height and width of a widget to 100 , 50 respectively. how should i do this using your solution

Comment: height: 100.0 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicPixelRatio , width: 50.0 * MediaQuery.of(context).devicPixelRatio ,

Comment: Actually this is not a very reliable solution because devices can have ALOT of pixels per logical pixel and the spaces can be too big .

Comment: Thanks @OmarBoshra for your feedback! I'll check and return back to you.

Answer (score 0):

i applied this way :

```
 class SizeConfig {
          static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
          static double screenWidth;
          static double screenHeight;
          static double blockSizeHorizontal;
          static double blockSizeVertical;

          void init(BuildContext context) {
           _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
           screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
           screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
           blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
           blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;
          }
         } 

  class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {  @override  Widget
 build(BuildContext context) {  SizeConfig().init(context);  …  } }
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
       child: Container(
        height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 20,
        width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 50,
        color: Colors.orange,
       ),
      );
     }
```

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a